# What variables should I consider in my diff-in-diff equation?

Tags: regression, panel-data, difference-in-difference

I know that at first the question might seem dumb - and perhaps it is, idk - but here's the thing... Let's say I made an intervetion in one city and didn't make in another. We usually prepare a dataframe with a column having the dummy of threatment (0 for the group and 1 for the test) and a dummy for the time of the intervention (0 if it's before the period of intervention and 1 if it's post-intervention). Something like the author of this post made: https://medium.com/dataman-in-ai/identify-causality-by-difference-in-differences-78ad8335fb7c.

So, let's say the intervention is the raise of minimum wage. Basically we have this:

```
dummy_city       dummy_period        period_x_city    var_1      var_2     employment
1                0                   0                100        1         50
0                0                   0                500        0         150
0                0                   0                200        0         120
1                0                   0                140        1         100
1                1                   1                120        0         130
```

We're checking if the raise of minimum wage is affecting the employment. The third column, period_x_city is the result of the multiplication between the first two columns. So the third column is the column we want to see if is significant. The last column is the target variable. The other two columns are just some extra information we want to consider in our regression.

Finally, my question: should I consider the first and second dummy in the regression? By considering them, will I have a multicollinearity problem?

I'm asking this because the first link I presented, the one from Medium, is not considering the two dummies. However, the book Mastering Metrics is considering, as you can see the screenshot bellow. Sorry about the image, but it was the only way to show this. The image is from chapter 5 of the book. If anyone can help me with this question, by also providing some sort of explanation, I'll be thankful.

[image]

Comment: The variable `dummy_period` is a post-treatment indicator. It should ‘switch on’ for *all units* after the intervention commences. Again, this dummy is time-subscripted; it should exhibit the same pattern within each city. Is that the case? It is difficult to tell with the small subset of data you provided.